# Is it possible to run a 3ph 220/440V motor on a standard 120/240V home circuit?

Tags: converter, voltage-source, tools

I have only basic knowledge in electronics and am looking for advice.

I have the opportunity to get a really good deal on a Band Saw, a Jet J8203K. A manual for this saw can be found here http://pdfstream.manualsonline.com/9/964a3ee1-de46-4476-9a6b-a82d8d2d1b9b.pdf

The problem is that this is an industrial quality saw with a 3ph motor supplied with 220/440V. Currently my workshop is powered with a long extension cord running from the kitchen with a 120/240V connection. As it is my table saw has tripped the 20A breaker when other things are running in the kitchen.

Is there a safe way to operate this saw given my circumstances? Are there converters that will step up 240V to 440V? I'm not in a position to afford major electrical updates.

In fact, since I'm asking, is it unsafe to be operating my 14A table saw on a 20A circuit with a 100ft extension cord?

Thanks for any/ all advice!

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you cannot run a 3-phase motor from a single-phase power source without some sort of external phase converter.  These are usually motor-generator sets with a single-phase drive motor powering a 3-phase generator that will provide 3-phase power to your equipment.  Unfortunately these are often fairly expensive.
2. NO, it's NOT SAFE to run a high-current device like a 14A saw on a 100' extension cord.  Chances are it's a consumer-grade cord, like 14 ga or even smaller and it's causing the saw to draw excess power and blow your circuit breaker.

Get your shop powered correctly!

Comment: You can purchase a VFD that will do the the conversion and give you variable speed as well but before you do variable speed be sure the motor will survive the frequency changes otherwise set it for 60Hz and forget it. Google: "single phase to 3 phase converter you will find lots of them and even the China suppliers such as AliExpress sell them.

Comment: @Gil A proper VFD is incredibly expensive, and requires you to use special also-expensive wire to avoid radiating absurd amounts of noise. I'm not sure I'd trust a cheap one from aliexpress.

Comment: @Gil Hmm. Looking at the device in question, a VFD is a better option than I'd initially thought. You still definitely don't want a cheap one off aliexpress, though. At least get one from a supplier like McMaster or Grainger.

Comment: I found them for less then $100 from several sources. I guess that may be incredibly expensive for some. Most of these are typically used in an industrial application where the wiring is in grounded metallic tubing (cheap shielding).  Most sources will give your money back if you are not happy.

Answer (score 0):

Getting this running is not going to be cheap.

The ideal option would be to get three-phase service to your workshop with a fairly high current, which may or may not be possible depending on where you live and how much you're willing to pay the electrician. Probably a good idea to get 440 or 480 V 3φ service, but if you can't 208 V 3φ would be fine, you'd just need a three-phase transformer to run this device.

The cheaper option would be to get split-phase service from your existing breaker panel *properly* wired over to your workshop. You'll want the 240 V outlet in addition to some 120 V ones. Then you use a phase converter, such as [this](https://www.mcmaster.com/7331K24) one that can run things at up to 70% of their rated power, or [this](https://www.mcmaster.com/7331K11) one that can operate things at 100% rated power (these are both 1 hp ones, which is enough to run your new band saw but not anything else in addition to it; you may want more power if you can afford it, just in case), and since those don't change voltage, use [a three-phase transformer](https://www.mcmaster.com/70525K83/) on the output to step it up to what the band saw expects.

---

I initially thought that a variable frequency drive, as suggested by a user in another answer's comments, would be a bad choice, since I didn't realize the speed adjustment was done via mechanical means and not electrical ones--I thought it had a VFD in the cabinet already to drive the motor. But since the motor *is* operating at a fixed speed, it would actually work.

What you would need to do is get a suitably-rated VFD ([here](https://www.mcmaster.com/variable-frequency-drives)'s a few)--that means rated for *more* output power than the thing requires, by the way--set it to a fixed 60 Hz (your motor is probably not rated to be run at other speeds! You may damage it if you try to run it at other speeds.), then you'll need to hook that up (with proper VFD cable!) to your band saw. Don't adjust the speed using the VFD; just use the saw's existing speed control system. Note that the band saw *can* be run on 240 V AC 3φ; the motor is rated for 230 V 3φ, and should be fine anywhere within 10% or so of there. It probably won't run on 208 V, hence the need for the transformer in the second option above.

---

As for your second question, I'd still recommend getting split-phase service brought out to your workshop. You're going to want it, and using such high current on a standard consumer-grade extension cord is not a great plan. If you *must* use an extension cord, get a high-end contractor-grade one, one that uses very thick wire. A 12/3 or even 10/3 extension cord would be the way to go. This won't be cheap.

A 14 A load on a 20 A circuit is also a bit much, considering the circuit will also have other loads on it, since it's your kitchen. Put it on a 30 A breaker at least.

Comment: Thanks, this was super helpful! I think I'm going to let the good deal on the bandsaw slip by. 

I did double check my extension chord. It's 12/3 rated for 125V, 15A, so just enough for my purposes. 

I hope to afford electrifying the garage properly next summer.

Comment: I wouldn't trust a 15 A rated cable for 14 A loads, especially not motors. Motors tend to draw several times their rated current before they get to full speed.